# How to test if my React container component renders all children

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing

I'm trying to create tests for a component that maps and array of notifications into notification components and renders them. I want to know that this component renders all child components. Here is the component I am trying to test:

```
import React from 'react';
import BasicNotification from './BasicNotification';

const NotificationContainer = ({ notifications }) => (
  <>
    {notifications.map((notification) => (
      <BasicNotification
        key={notification.id}
        id={notification.id}
        message={notification.message}
        severity={notification.severity}
        data-testid='notify-test'
      />
    ))}
  </>
);

export default NotificationContainer;
```

and here is what my test currently looks like:

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { expect, it } from 'vitest';
import { NotificationContainer } from '../../../src/components/Notification';
import { NotificationContext } from '../../../src/contexts/NotificationContext';

const MockNotificationContainer = ({ notifications }) => {
  <NotificationContext.Provider value={{ notificationsObject: { state: notifications } }}>
    <NotificationContainer />
  </NotificationContext.Provider>;
};

it('renders all the notifications from notification context', () => {
  const notifications = [
    { id: 34345, message: 'this is a test', severity: 'success' },
    { id: 45555, message: 'this is a test', severity: 'error' },
    { id: 32235, message: 'this is a test', severity: 'info' }
  ];

  const { getAllByTestId } = render(<MockNotificationContainer notifications={notifications} />);

  const allNotifications = getAllByTestId('notify-test');

  expect(allNotifications.length).toBe(3);
});
```

I tried to run this expecting that allNotifications.length would be three but its unable to find elements with the specified test id. I know I'm doing something wrong but is this even a valid approach?

Thanks in advance for any feedback.

Comment: Are you actually passing the test ID attribute onto the rendered element inside the basic notification component? Can you show that component

Comment: @Jayce444 I can see in my output that the test is only rendering a body tag with a div inside it. I think this means that I have a problem with how I am mocking my component and the routes not being correct. I should maybe delete this thread?